# Populating alternate columns in excel based on conditional formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a number of features in my dataset, each of which is divided into actual and target responses based on a survey. I want to create a conditional format where if the respondents do not have an answer leaving the actual value blank, I would like to populate it to be 1. And in the same way, if the actual response is recorded and there is no target value, I want to populate each of those cases with a 5 for the target. Could someone please throw some light on how I could do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You won't be able to use a conditional format to place a value in a cell.  You'd need a macro do to that.  Conditional Formatting can only do just that, format.  If you want to use a helper column, you can simply do like `=If(A1="",1,If(A1=[target value],5,""))` I think.

Comment: Is use of "Helper" columns OK so that your source data is preserved?